# 15 year old software wont run on my new W10 machine, because "operating system is not adequate"

Tags: windows-10, windows-xp, compatibility

Ive got a c. 15 year old .exe programme.

Ive tried to run it on my new w10 laptop (purchased from Dell in 2020) which has a 1 GHZ i5 CPU in it. This new laptop seems to run all my other programmes very fast and as i understand the CPU is clocked slow to aide power consumption, but can boost up to something like 2.5GHZ. In real world tests this laptop is actually very fast at running most things i ask it to do. See screenshot below.

[image: screenshot of system specs]

The problem is that when i try and install this .exe programme i get an error saying that the "operating system is not adequate". Ive tried to run this programme in WXP-SP2 and SP3 compatibility mode, but still get the same error. Ive also tried running as an admin, but this dosnt fix the issue.

[image: screenshot of error when attempting install]

My conclusion is that although the error states that its a OS compatibility issue, that the software is actually checking the hardware and concluding that it cant be run, because the CPU speed is too small / low. Although in reality it will run fine, the software in question is not particularly complex.

Any thoughts on how i could get this to work ?

Comment: “Any thoughts on how i could get this to work?” - If the application requires a more powerful GPU in order to run there isn’t a way to run it on the hardware you describe

Comment: @Ramhound apologies.. i meant CPU.. will update question

Comment: Have you tried running a more recent version of the application. The fact I was able to find zero information on this software makes it difficult to do research

Comment: You might want to look into running that software in a Windows 2000 or XP virtual machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could install it in [VirtualBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox) or [Virtual PC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Virtual_PC) (if you install Windows XP on it).

Comment: That would be reasonable. I have XP machines here in my VMware Workstation.

Answer (score 2):

This software is very old. The most advanced version is for Windows XP.

So the message you got really means it is not compliant beyond XP; not that your new Windows 10 machine is not powerful enough.

[HW Illumination](http://files.lutron.com/hwi/software/full_116_HOV.htm)

> HomeWorks Illumination Software is approved to work with Windows
> 2000, and XP operating systems.

Comment: does compatibility mode not fix the OS mix match problem ?

Comment: Nothing that old - no.

Comment: Compatibility mode in the UI is a collection of common compat shims, not all compat shims. See the full toolkit here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/planning/compatibility-administrator-users-guide